# R - Shiny - How to Export an entire tab panel into png/pdf/excel?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyapps

I've created a dashboard (*with shinyUI/shinydashboard package*) which has a designed table using GT package.

I'm trying to export the entire panel/formatted table as pdf/image/(data in excel) but don't know how to do that.

Is there any way to achieve my requirement?

I've mentioned below the simplified version of script I'm using.

Thanks...

Script:

```
TableA = data.frame(Product = c('iPhone', 'Macbook', 'Airpod', 'Macbook', 'Airpod', 'Macbook', 'iPhone'), East = c(1:7), West = c(5:11), North = c(15:21), South = c(24:30))

library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(DT)
library(rhandsontable)
library(tidyverse)
library(tidyquant)
library(knitr)
library(gt)
library(shinycssloaders)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)

header = dashboardHeader(title = 'Shiny Dashboard', titleWidth = 400)

sidebar = dashboardSidebar()

body <- dashboardBody(uiOutput("mainpanel"))

ui = dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body)

############

server = function(input, output, session)
  
{
  
  output$mainpanel = renderUI({
      
      fluidRow(tabBox(width = 250, height = 100,
               tabPanel("Apple Sales", value = 'tab1', gt_output(outputId = "TableC")%>% withSpinner(color="#3483CA", type = 1, size = 2), downloadButton(outputId = "Downloadpng", label = "Download Png"))
      ))
    })
    
    
    TableB = as.data.frame(TableA) %>%
      
            gt() %>%
            
            grand_summary_rows(columns = 2:5, fns = list(TotalSales = "sum")) %>%
            
            tab_options(grand_summary_row.background.color = "#DDEBF7") %>%
            
            cols_width(columns = 1 ~ px(1), columns = 2 ~ px(300), everything() ~ px(100)) %>%
            
            tab_spanner(label = "Sales", columns = 3:6)
      
    output$TableC = render_gt(expr = TableB)
  
  
  output$Downloadpng = downloadHandler(filename = "Apple Sales.png", 
  
          content = function(file)
              
            {
              png(file)
              with(tabPanel == 'tab1')
              dev.off()
            }
  )
  
}


############

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a good use-case for `shinyscreenshot` package. You can use the `screenshotButton` function and pass the `id` of the area that you want the image of.

```
library(shinyscreenshot)

header = dashboardHeader(title = 'Shiny Dashboard', titleWidth = 400)

sidebar = dashboardSidebar()

body <- dashboardBody(uiOutput("mainpanel"))

ui = dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body)

############

server = function(input, output, session)
  
{
  
  output$mainpanel = renderUI({
    
    fluidRow(tabBox(width = 250, height = 100,
          tabPanel("Apple Sales", value = 'tab1',
            gt_output(outputId = "TableC")%>% 
              withSpinner(color="#3483CA", type = 1, size = 2), 
            
            screenshotButton(selector="#TableC", label = 'Download Png', filename = 'screenshot')
    )))
  })
  
  
  TableB = as.data.frame(TableA) %>%
    
    gt() %>%
    
    grand_summary_rows(columns = 2:5, fns = list(TotalSales = "sum")) %>%
    
    tab_options(grand_summary_row.background.color = "#DDEBF7") %>%
    
    cols_width(columns = 1 ~ px(1), columns = 2 ~ px(300), everything() ~ px(100)) %>%
    
    tab_spanner(label = "Sales", columns = 3:6)
  
  output$TableC = render_gt(expr = TableB)
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

After clicking on `'Download PNG'` button this returns the following image.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much Ronak.
Is there any way to export the dashboard in pdf and excel versions as well?

Comment: I think that would require a very different approach which would be very broad for this post.

Comment: Can you suggest from where can I get help for that?

Comment: You can ask a new question for it.

Comment: Thanks Ronak. I've raised a new question and the link is given below.
Please help me if you have time...

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67458247/r-shiny-how-to-export-an-entire-tab-panel-into-pdf-excel